# how get openrc file by `openstack application credential create` or identity api application_credentials

Tags: file, openstack, identity, credentials, keystone

Such as this **Download openrc file** operation:

[image]

Or get the `openrc file` by [Identity API](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/index.html?expanded=create-application-credential-detail#create-application-credential).

Question: how can I get the **openrc file** by `openstack application credential create` command or the **Identity API** instead of **click** the **Download openrc file** button in dashboard.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. You seem to state the methods for obtaining application credentials. Is there a problem?

Comment: The application credential is not the same as the openrc file. From the docs: "Users can create application credentials to allow their applications to authenticate to keystone."

Comment: @BakaKuna I know, I only want to get the **openrc file** which is generated by `openstack application credential create`, such as the **Download** button's function.

Comment: But the command `openstack application credential created` does never generate an openrc file. I'm sorry if I don't understand your question, but I'm pretty sure the only way to get an openrc generated for you, is by downloading it from Horizon. The cli does not have this functionality.

Comment: Yes, It doesn't generate openrc file but will show the key info after execute the `openstack application credential create`, I can't find any method to get the **openrc file** by `command line` or `Identity API`.